# Query display result with while() or foreach()

Tags: php, mysqli

I was messing around with how to do queries from MySQL and show them on PHP and I stumbled upon something:

This is the table I'm doing the query to:
[image: This is the table im doing the query to]

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM notas");

while($nota = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    var_dump($nota);
    echo $nota["Descripcion"];
}
```

Whenever I use a while() to display all the results of the query, it works. This table have 2 rows and both of them are showing.

Result of the var_dump($notas):
[image: Result of the var_dump($notas)]

But whenever I use a foreach(), it just returns me the last result of the query.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM notas");

foreach(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) as $valor){
    var_dump($valor);
}
```

Result of the var_dump($valor):
[image: Result of the var_dump($valor)]

Is there any reason why? I'm doing something wrong in the foreach() loop? I really can't tell. I would just say "fudge it", accept it and only use while loops to display queries, but, you know, want to know if I was doing something wrong or not understanding something.

Comment: See [mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). That'll work for your foreach. Reason `_fetch_assoc` doesn't work is it only returns one row at a time & increments an internal pointer, so the next time it's called it retrieves the next row. For a `foreach`, you need an array or an [iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

Comment: `foreach($query` but you should use some error reporting so you know query executed successfully

Comment: Using `while( _fetch_assoc())` is good if you're working with a huge number of rows and might use too much memory if you put ALL of the results into an array at once.

Comment: Also, I personally recommend using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) over `mysqli`. I've always found it easier to use & I like it's api for binding paramaters. But it's also not a crucial switch, so don't let my recommendation distract you from what you're trying to accomplish. I just think its a better developer experience.

Comment: @Reed I see. Used `_fetch_all` and it indeed worked, the `var_dump` now returned the two rows I was expecting. I'll keep in mind what you're saying about the rows and PDO (havent used it yet so might as well look into it). Thx c:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second version is looping through the columns, not the rows. It's equivalent to:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
foreach ($row as $valor) {
    var_dump($valor);
}
```

You can see here that it's just fetching one row, which is an associative array, then looping through the elements of that array.

`foreach (<expression> as <variable>)` doesn't re-evaluate the expression every time through the loop. It executes it once, saves that array, then loops through the array elements.

The `mysqli_result` object is iterable, so you can do:

```
foreach($query as $valor) {
    var_dump($valor);
}
```

You can also call `mysqli_fetch_all($query)`, which will return a 2-dimensional array of all the results, and then loop through that. But if the query returns many results, this will use lots of memory.

Comment: I see. Didnt understand well how the `fetch_assoc` and `fetch_all` worked. Also, never tried using `mysqli_result` for handling results of a query, might as well try it out see how that goes. Thx c: